How to get current frame of a player in JLayer? Implementing `pause()` method
I'm trying to write a mp3 player in java.
I want to implement the pause() method, which stores the frame that the player (AdvancedPlayer) has stopped. The the resume() method starts the player from the stored frame.
The AudioHandler class:
public class AudioHandler {
    private AdvancedPlayer player;
    private Thread playThread;
    Bitstream stream; 
    private boolean playing = false;
    private boolean paused;
    private int pausedOnFrame;
    private Track currTrack;

    /*
     * Handling the playing of an mp3 instance
     * @param track Track instance that carries the path that the player can play
     */
    public void play(Track track){
        String path = track.getPath();
        currTrack = track; 

        if(!playing){
            playing = true;
            paused = false;
            pausedOnFrame = 0; 
// Thread handling is needed cause I will implement a SwiftGUI 
            playThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path)) {
                    stream = new Bitstream(fis);
                    player = new AdvancedPlayer(
                    player.play(pausedOnFrame, Integer.MAX_VALUE); 
                }
                catch (JavaLayerException | IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
                finally{ 
                    playing = false;
                    pausedOnFrame = 0;
                }
            });
            playThread.start();
        }
        else System.out.println("Alredy playing.");
    } // end of 

    /*
     * Stops the thread and the player
     * Sets the playing to false
     */
    public void stop() {
    // ...
    } 

    /*
     * Sets the paused to true
     * Closes the player == pauses the player at the frame
     */
    public void pause() throws BitstreamException {
        if (playing && !paused) {
            System.out.println(stream.readFrame());
            player.close(); 
            paused = true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Resumes playback from where it was paused
     */
    public void resume() {
        if (paused) {
            paused = false; 
            play(currTrack, pausedOnFrame); // Start playing again from the saved path
        }
    }


} // end of class


The Main where i call them:
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Track asd = "/path/to/song.mp3";
            AudioHandler plr = new AudioHandler(); 
           
            String input;
            while(true){
                input = reader.readLine();
                if(input.equals("exit")) System.exit(0);
                if(input.equals("play")) plr.play(asd);
                if(input.equals("stop")) plr.stop();
                if(input.equals("pause")) plr.pause();
                if(input.equals("resume")) plr.resume();
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e){}

    } // end of main method
} // end of Main class

The Player class had a getFrame() method, but dont have a play() method that works with a stored frame. (So i cant do play(fromThisFrame, Integer.MAX_VALUE);)
I cant find the documentation and Im not good enough to read it from the code.
This is an assignment project's test branch, so please don't roast the code to the full extend just yet. I will make it prettier and safer, but i just want to have bare minimum to start on the other stuffs.
I will edit the code and the post on the way. Feel free to edit the question and make it more understandable if I did not do a good enough job.

I tried to switch to JavaFX but that did not compile.
I tried to read the library's source code, but that did not help.
I refactored the code a numerous times and this is the current state
I tried to use chatGPT and codium to solve this problem, but they did not provide a working solution. (The current code is mostly based on ChatGPT-s answer cause this seemed like closer to what i have expected.)

EDIT: library source

Is the library the github javazoom.jl.player.advance.AdvancedPlayer ?  Also, I would assume you meant "The the resume() method starts the player..." in second paragraph.  If so, it does have a public boolean play(final int start, final int end) which seems to fit your needs.  Seems the jlayer tag is for something else although it frequently is used for this mp3 library?

Yes. library source. I'll edit the post, thank you! Yep, but my problem is that i cant get the frame of the currently playing song.

I see - well since the AdvancedPlayer is not final you could extend it by either a) modifying close method to return a frame counter (maintained in decodeFrame) or b) have the decodeFrame method invoke a callback for every frame.  (a) seems easier.  Note the doc for decocdeFrame is exactly wrong - it returns true if there are more frames to decode.

Extending the AdvancedPlayer is a great idea, i did not think about that. Thank you. I will try it.
